# Select values from noise contours across one road stretch

Tags: arcgis-pro, select, road

I have a map of noise contours across a city and am using ArcGIS Pro.

I want to select one road (not straight) and export the noise values along that road to a table but I'm having trouble selecting the road. I only have the basemap and noise contour layer.

I don't have coordinates for the road so how can I manually select the road area? Should I draw a line or a polygon (how to do this manually)? And how to do it so that I can extract the noise values it intersects with?

I'm new to GIS and haven't found a solution online.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138633/discussion-on-question-by-speck-select-values-from-noise-contours-across-one-roa).

Comment: Please add that as an answer not a comment